# RecyclerView con orden inverso

Tags: mysql, recyclerview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo mi RecyclerView que obtiene los datos de mi base de datos MySQL mediante json. El caso es que cuando ejecuto la app y ésta obtiene los datos remotos, siempre me poner el elemento con id 1 al principio de la lista y los demás detrás ordenados de forma ascendente.

Necesito lo opuesto, es decir, que  los elementos con id más alto figuren primero y los elementos con la id menor al final.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, en la primera imagen aparecen los elementos añadidos antes, y en la segunda los últimos items añadidos, quiero que sea al revés, que los últimos ítem añadidos aparezcan al principio y los items añadidos antes al final.

*Es decir, como ordenarlos por fecha*

Definición de clase Meta:

```
public class Meta {

    private static final String TAG = Meta.class.getSimpleName();
    /*
        Atributos
         */
    private String idMeta;
    private String titulo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String prioridad;
    private String fechaLim;
    private String categoria;

    public Meta(String idMeta,
                String titulo,
                String descripcion,
                String fechaLim,
                String categoria,
                String prioridad) {
        this.idMeta = idMeta;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.prioridad = prioridad;
        this.fechaLim = fechaLim;
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getIdMeta() {
        return idMeta;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getPrioridad() {
        return prioridad;
    }

    public String getFechaLim() {
        return fechaLim;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    /**
     * Compara los atributos de dos metas
     *
     * @param meta Meta externa
     * @return true si son iguales, false si hay cambios
     */
    public boolean compararCon(Meta meta) {
        return this.titulo.compareTo(meta.titulo) == 0 &&
                this.descripcion.compareTo(meta.descripcion) == 0 &&
                this.fechaLim.compareTo(meta.fechaLim) == 0 &&
                this.categoria.compareTo(meta.categoria) == 0 &&
                this.prioridad.compareTo(meta.prioridad) == 0;
    }
}
```

MetaAdapter:

```
/**
 * Adaptador del recycler view
 */
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Meta> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Meta> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.titulo.setText(items.get(i).getTitulo());
        viewHolder.prioridad.setText(items.get(i).getPrioridad());
        viewHolder.fechaLim.setText(items.get(i).getFechaLim());
        viewHolder.categoria.setText(items.get(i).getCategoria());
    }

    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getIdMeta());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView titulo;
        public TextView prioridad;
        public TextView fechaLim;
        public TextView categoria;
        public ItemClickListener listener;

        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            prioridad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prioridad);
            fechaLim = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            categoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoria);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Donde se carga el RecyclerView lista:

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

 ...
 /*
 Adaptador del recycler view
 */
 private MetaAdapter adapter;
 /* 
 Instancia global del recycler view 
 */
 private RecyclerView lista;

 ...


    /**
     * Interpreta los resultados de la respuesta y así
     * realizar las operaciones correspondientes
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json con la respuesta
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Obtener atributo "estado"
            String estado = response.getString("estado");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1": // EXITO
                    // Obtener array "metas" Json
                    JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                    // Parsear con Gson
                    Meta[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta[].class);
                    // Inicializar adaptador
                    adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
                    // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case "2": // FALLIDO
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Te sugiero, que añadas tus códigos, si no, no  te podrán ayudar, ya que es muy redundante, no hay nada donde sostenerse, saludos !

Comment: Es cierto añade código para guiarnos según lo que tienes avanzado.

Comment: os paso el link de la app https://www.dropbox.com/s/a657nyoqdjo0nf7/I_Wish.rar?dl=0 , hay esta l app

Comment: No queda claro si necesitas ordenarlo de forma descendente por idMeta o por fechaLim, podrías aclarar cual de los dos ordenes necesitas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar la lista, puedes utilizar la clase **Arrays** (ver: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Implementación: Para ordenar por idMeta de forma descendente, puedes aplicar la siguiente modificación en el método **procesarRespuesta** de la clase **MainFragment**:

...

```
                // Obtener array "metas" Json
                JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                // Parsear con Gson
                Meta[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta[].class);

                // APLICACIÓN DE ORDEN: 
                // Ordenar el array de metas por idMeta de forma descendente:
                Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator<Meta>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(meta objeto1, meta objeto2) {
                        int result;
                        // Comparamos por idMeta, de forma descendente:
                        result = objeto2.idMeta.compareTo(objeto1.idMeta);
                        /* 
                        // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                        result = objeto2.fechaLim.compareTo(objeto1.fechaLim);
                        */
                        return result;

                    }
                });
                // Fin del ordenamiento.

                // Inicializar adaptador
                adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
                // Setear adaptador a la lista
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

...

Entiendo es lo que necesitas para lograr el orden deseado. Espero te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: Graciasss muchisimas gracias, funciono

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Solo una duda más, si quisiera aprovechar mis cuadros de texto de la fecha para ordenarlos como lo haría, es decir que la fecha que es más tarde ej 1-1-2018 aparezca primero y la fecha de hace más tiempo ej 2-7-2017 aparezca al final

Comment: Cómo se podría hacer?